# Edit "PermitRootLogin yes",

Tags: permissions, read-only

I am trying to edit "PermitRootLogin yes" to "PermitRootLogin no" on a VM ESXi host.  When I try to edit it using VI at /etc/ssh/sshd_config, it is in Read Only mode.  I tried the override wq! and it is not saving.  I get SSHD is "Read Only".  How can I edit this file?  I am logged in as root.

Comment: You've provided no OS & release details; nor details as to if the RO relates to a *file-system* which cannot be changed (if you're system is one where the *fs* is *squashfs* or a RO type you can only use it & not make changes as you're trying - but we don't know your OS & release details which are a start as that lets us know your product).

Comment: Sorry I missed that.  Its a VMware ESXi 6.7 U3 (build 17700523) host.

Comment: What is the *exact* Guest OS? Which release? Did you actually install it? Or are you trying to edit the installer's environment?

Comment: I did not install it. I installed VMware ESXi 6.7. I am editing the installers environment in ESXi 6.7.

Comment: What is the exact Guest OS? Which release?

Comment: That's what I was trying to explain.  ESXi use to run on a Linux kernel now it does not include Linux.  ESXi runs on it own vmkernel called  microkernel.  The build is VMware ESXi 6.7 U3 (build 17700523).